# Latex Letter template with sidebar

Tags: latex, letter, xelatex

I'm looking for someone who can tell me how to make this letter template in LaTeX, i currently using a template made in word. I'm wondering where it's possible to make the same template in LaTeX.

Background info:

Two fonts are used: Garamond and Arial
Fontsize: 12 and 16

Must support Tabular, minipage and figure environment

[image: Letter template written in MS-Word]

Comment: 1) Questions on LaTeX should go to the dedicated [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) site. 2) Of course it is possible to make such a template, but you have to invest some time in that. What have you already tried? Have you looked at the `letter` or `scrlttr2` classes?

Comment: My normal template is the following:

Comment: [A Preview of my normal template][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xeWmL.png

Answer (score 1):

```
    My normal preamble is the following (which i have used a lot of time writing):

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}

% commands from fontspec  

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont[Scale=1.2]{Garamond}

\newfontfamily\gmd{Garamond}

\newfontfamily\DTL{DTL Argo}

\newfontfamily\subsubsectionfont{Helvetica Neue}

%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{\thesection}{1.8cm}{}[{\titlerule[0.4pt]}]

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\thesubsection}{1.6cm}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1.4cm}{}

% commands from titlesec

\newcommand*{\Stor}{\@setfontsize\Stor{30pt}{30pt}}

\titleformat*{\section}{\gmd\fontsize{28pt}{30pt}\selectfont}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\gmd\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\selectfont}

\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\subsubsectionfont}

% Document properties

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[pdftex]{geometry}

\geometry{margin=1.3in}

\geometry{top=1.4in}

\geometry{bottom=1.4in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage[hang,nooneline]{subfigure}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{multirow}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{arydshln}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{mdframed}

% Footnote font
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

\newfontfamily\gmd{Garamond}
%\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\normalsize\gmd}{}{}
\let\footnotesize\small

\makeatother

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

\setlength\footnotemargin{7.05pt}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \kern 3pt
  \hrule width \textwidth height 0.4pt
  \kern 2.6pt
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
%\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%\numberwithin{table}{section}
%\numberwithin{program}{section}
%\numberwithin{boks}{section}
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Colors and lines

%\definecolor{fm}{RGB}{248,244,230}
\definecolor{fm}{RGB}{248,247,217}
\definecolor{borsen}{RGB}{254,232,215}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{4,19,73}
%\definecolor{Grå}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{Grå}{RGB}{217,217,217}
\newcommand{\gline}{\arrayrulecolor{Grå}\hline}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}}
\newcommand{\HHRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.5mm}}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{\par\hspace*{\labelsep}\textbullet\hspace*{\labelsep}}

\arrayrulecolor{Grå}

\DeclareCaptionFont{dblue}{\color{dblue}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{black}{\color{black}}

% commands from caption
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage[width={\textwidth}, margin=11pt , aboveskip=20pt, belowskip=6pt, font=footnotesize, labelfont={bf,dblue}, textfont={bf,black}, tableposition=top, figureposition=top,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false, labelsep={newline}]{caption}%

\newfontfamily\tablefont[Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}]{Arial}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setmainfont[Color=black, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Arial}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setmainfont[Color=black, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Arial}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{boks}{\setmainfont[Color=black, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Arial}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Liste %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlist[description]{
  style=multiline,
  font=\normalfont\gmd, % set the label font
  align=parleft, 
  topsep=5pt,
  labelwidth={0.06\textwidth},
  leftmargin=!, 
  parsep=0pt,
  before=\gmd
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%CEPOS Figure%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Finansministeriets figur %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{fmfigur}[4]{
\begin{figure}[htbp!] 
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,bgcolor=fm}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} @{}c@{}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{#1}\label{#2}
\end{minipage}
\\   
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{bil/#2.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
    \end{adjustbox}     \vspace{-0.5em}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\textwidth}
  {\gmd\small
    \begin{description}
    \item[{\  Anm.}:]#3
    \item[{\  Kilde}:]#4
    \end{description}}
\end{adjustbox}  \vspace{-1.75em}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 
} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%% Finansministeriets Side by Side figurer  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\FMADAM}[6]{
\begin{table}[htpb!]
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,bgcolor=fm} 
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-1pt} \arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} @{}c@{} | @{}c@{} } 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{#1}\label{#2}
\end{minipage}   
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{#3}\label{#4}
\end{minipage}    
\\
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{bil/#2.pdf}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{bil/#4.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-1pt} 
\end{tabular}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{adjustbox}     \vspace{-0.5em}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\textwidth}
  {\gmd\small
    \begin{description}
    \item[{\  Anm.}:]#5
    \item[{\  Kilde}:]#6
    \end{description}}
\end{adjustbox}  \vspace{-1.75em}
\end{center}
\end{table}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lop,
  name=Program
]{program}
% announce the float to subcaption and create the subprogram environment
\DeclareCaptionSubType{program}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lop,
  name=Boks
]{boks}
% announce the float to subcaption and create the subprogram environment
\DeclareCaptionSubType{boks}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FMTable%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\fmboks}[5]{
\begin{boks}[htbp!]
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,bgcolor=fm}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\caption{#1}\label{boks:#2}
\end{minipage}
    \fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont\centering
\begin{tabulary}{0.95\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}L@{}}
\onehalfspacing \fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont
    #3
\end{tabulary} 
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{adjustbox}      \vspace{-0.5em}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\textwidth}
  {\gmd\small
    \begin{description}
    \item[{\  Anm.}:]#4
    \item[{\  Kilde}:]#5
    \end{description}}
\end{adjustbox}  \vspace{-1.75em}
\end{center}
\end{boks} 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FMTable%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\fmtable}[5]{
\begin{table}[htbp!]
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,bgcolor=fm}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\caption{#1}\label{tab:#2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{center}
\begingroup
    \fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont\arrayrulecolor{Grå}
#3
\endgroup
\end{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\end{adjustbox}     \vspace{-0.5em}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.95\textwidth}
  {\gmd\small
    \begin{description}
    \item[{\  Anm.}:]#4
    \item[{\  Kilde}:]#5
    \end{description}}
\end{adjustbox}  \vspace{-1.75em}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeindex
\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{dblue}\hrule}{}{}
\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{dblue}\hrule}{}{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\makeindex

\DeclareMathOperator{\dlog}{dlog\!}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d\!}
\newcommand{\gmdit}[1]{\textit{\gmd #1}} 
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}                                  
\newcommand{\lrarrow}{\Leftrightarrow}              
\newcommand{\degree}{\text{\textdegree}}            
\newcommand{\rarrow}{\Rightarrow}                   
\newcommand{\larrow}{\Leftarrow}                    
\newcommand{\udarrow}{\Updownarrow}                 
\newcommand{\bsm}{\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}}   
\newcommand{\esm}{\end{smallmatrix} \right]}        
\newcommand{\shiftline}{\newline \newline}          
\newcommand{\PD}{\partial}              
\newcommand{\grad}{\nabla}  
\newcommand{\lb}{\left(}                        
\newcommand{\rb}{\right)}                       
\newcommand{\ohm}{\Omega}   
\newcommand{\Sun}{\ensuremath{\odot}}           
\newcommand{\g}{\cdot}                      
\newcommand{\limit}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{
\begin{align*}
\centering
#1
\end{align*}}
\newcommand{\matnr}[1]{
\begin{align}
\centering
#1
\end{align}}

\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}

\fancyhead[R]{{Ivan Erik Kragh}\\{(+45) 60 68 13 05}} % predefined ()
\fancyhead[L]{Opdatering: Ulighed og Working Poor (juli, 2016)} % 1. sectionname

\lfoot{\small }
\chead{\ }
%\rhead{\small Ivan Erik Kragh\\(+45) 60 68 13 05}
\cfoot{Side \thepage\ af \pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{ik@kraghinvest.dk}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    \textwidth=12in
    \begin{document}
     \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{4cm}p{6cm}}
      Navin & &28 September\\
      Firma & &2016
      \end{tabular}

    \textwidth=8in
   {\bf Kaer Navin}\\
   \small
   \vspace{2cm}
```

% here you can enter your paragraph
       This is what I get when I type to see the test page. That 
       must   be        crazy.

```
   \vspace{3cm}

  Med\\

  \line(1,0) {100}\\

   Tl: 123 456

   \vfill


   \hspace{2cm}Kevin etc. 

    \end{document}
```

% I think this format will be useful to you.